PowerShell - ConvertTo-Json how to get ndjson result
I am trying to split 1 NDJSON file into multiple NDJSON files. I am able to consume and split the file, but the problem is the resulting files are in JSON format. Is it possible to output to NDJSON format or do I have to do some string manipulation?
My input file test.json:
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38116"}

My powershell script so far:
$json = (Get-Content C:\Temp\test.json) | ConvertFrom-Json

$jnl_list = $json.JRNAL_NO | select -Unique

ForEach ($jnl in $jnl_list) {
    $Array = $json | Where-Object {$_.JRNAL_NO -eq $jnl}
    $res = ($Array | ConvertTo-Json)    
    $res | Out-File -FilePath .\JNL\$($jnl).json   
}

My current output. Here's the 38115.json file:
[
    {
        "PERIOD":  "2024004",
        "JRNAL_NO":  "38115"
    },
    {
        "PERIOD":  "2024004",
        "JRNAL_NO":  "38115"
    },
    {
        "PERIOD":  "2024004",
        "JRNAL_NO":  "38115"
    },
    {
        "PERIOD":  "2024004",
        "JRNAL_NO":  "38115"
    }
]


I need the output file to be NDJSON, basically the same format as the input file.
38115.json should be:
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}

38116.json should be:
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38116"}


If I understand correctly what you're looking for, the code my be greatly simplified by using Group-Object.
To get the NDJSON format what you can do is enumerate each object from the group of objects (.Group property) and pass it to ConvertTo-Json -Compress then send that output to your file.
$json = Get-Content C:\Temp\test.json | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($group in $json | Group-Object JRNAL_NO) {
    $group.Group |
        ForEach-Object { $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress } |
        Set-Content ".\JNL\$($group.Name).json"
}

Code above with the sample data would be creating 2 files:

38115.json

{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}
{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38115"}


38116.json

{"PERIOD":"2024004","JRNAL_NO":"38116"}


I took it that the OP wants the output to be in a similar format as the input (NDJSON - one full json document per line), just filtered by the JRNAL_NO into separate files - something like $_.group | foreach-object { $_ | convertto-json -compress } | join-string -separator "`n" | set-content  ".\JNL\$($_.Name).json" maybe...

@mclayton totally, thank you will add an update :D first time I hear about NDJSON

@SantiagoSquarzon - npyw. Fwiw, I’d known it previously as “json lines”, so the name NDJSON is new to me as well :-) - https://jsonlines.org/

@anhtle glad it helped!

@mclayton I knew it existed, ADX (azure data explorer) can use this format for ingestion but didn't know this format had a name :P

There's a [tag:jsonlines] tag, which I've added to the question. https://jsonlines.org/ (aka JSONL) seems to be the actively maintained specification, whereas http://ndjson.org/ (aka NDJSON and formerly LDJSON) is now defunct (links to an unrelated site in Korean). The umbrella term for this one-JSON-object-at-a-time format is JSON streaming.

To anyone reading this who has a score of 5 or more in the [tag:ndjson] tag and a reputation of 25,000 or  more: please suggest [tag:jsonlines] lines as a synonym at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ndjson/synonyms

To complement the helpful answer from Santiago Squarzon with a presumably more performant solution:
You could also consider to distribute the original lines ("same format as the input file") one-by-one on the fly using the steppable pipeline as in this example where you only use the ConvertTo-Json result to determine the "JRNAL_NO" value:
$Pipeline = @{}
Get-Content .\test.json |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        $Jnl = ($_ | ConvertFrom-Json).JRNAL_NO
        if (!$Pipeline.Contains($Jnl)) {
            $Pipeline[$Jnl] = { Set-Content .\$Jnl.json }.GetSteppablePipeline()
            $Pipeline[$Jnl].Begin($True)
        }
        $Pipeline[$Jnl].Process($_)
    } -End {
        foreach ($Key in $Pipeline.Keys) { $Pipeline[$Key].End() }
    }

For more details and background, see: Mastering the (steppable) pipeline
